# How to format and read this kind of CSV file in C#

Tags: c#, csv

Here is just an example of the data I need to read from csv file.
How get the first row as a name of the all columns?
How to parse this data?
(I will use the data to draw a graphs)

> Year;I1;I2;I3;II1;III2 
>  2012;2.4;3.1;1.2;3.7;0.8
>   2007;-1.1;-5.1;-2.5;-0.8;0.6
>  2001;3.9;4.4;1.8;2.4;5.9

Thanks for all who helped me, i solved my problem, thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a specialized library for this - [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) is a popular third party choice:

> The FileHelpers are a free and easy to use .NET library to import/export data from fixed length or delimited records in files, strings or streams.

If you must use Microsoft libraries, [`TextFieldParser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO` namespace can also be used:

> Provides methods and properties for parsing structured text files.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I know how much new lists I will need to create for each file, as example in this situation i need 4 lists? but if i got a much bigger file with much more values? Main question is how to make the needed count of list for each file..

Comment: @Kristian - Did you look at the library? It will parse a file that you specify and give you the number of lines in it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to read the file line by line, and use [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) to split it up by `';'` into an array.

- [How to: Read a Text File One Line at a Time (Visual C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94223t4d.aspx)

Comment: In previous program i used something like this:
if (line != null)  {   a.Add(Double.Parse(line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf(";"))));   But now its not working becouse i never know how much rows will be in the file...

Answer (score 0):

Another free tool is the [CSV Reader](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader). No Need to invent the wheel over and over again ;)